# multiple subnets definition in terraform local variable

Tags: azure-virtual-network, terraform-provider-azure, subnet

```
locals {
  fw-subnet-ids = var.env == "dev" || var.env == "qa" ? data.azurerm_subnet.storage-fw-subnets-lower[*].id : data.azurerm_subnet.storage-fw-subnets-upper[*].id
}
```

I am using `fw-subnet-ids` as local var and using it to set firewall rule on storage account resources.
I want to change  this  rule so that now
for dev and qa  both ...lower[*].id and ....upper[*].id are allowed
for uat&prod only  ....upper[*].id  subnet allowed.

How can I update the local block to make it possible?

Comment: Any updates on the question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this requirement, you need to set the limitation for the value of the variable `env` that it must be one of the four inputs `dev, qa, uat, prod` and can't be null. Then you can change the locals like this:

```
locals {
  fw-subnet-ids = var.env == "dev" || var.env == "qa" ? concat(data.azurerm_subnet.storage-fw-subnets-lower[*].id, data.azurerm_subnet.storage-fw-subnets-upper[*].id) : data.azurerm_subnet.storage-fw-subnets-upper[*].id
}
```

It means if the variable `env` is anyone of the two `dev, qa`, even both of them, return the list that combines the lists ...lower[].id and ....upper[].id. If the variable `env` is not one of them, it must be one of the `uat, prod` or both, then return the list ....upper[*].id.